# How to validate the DateTime string format "2018-01-22T18:23:00.000Z" in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, datetime

I need to validate in my code if the format of the `DateTime` string `2018-01-22T18:23:00.000Z` is a valid one or not.

Regex solution or any other solution is fine.Can someone help me doing this?

Comment: is valid based on what format? also, what did you tried?

Comment: Does it have to be a UTC time or are timezone offsets also allowed? What are your validation rules?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`2018-01-22T18:23:00.000Z` is the ISO 8601 format for an instant. So you may just use `Instant.parse("2018-01-22T18:23:00.000Z")`. Catch a `DateTimeParseException` from the case where the string isn’t valid, either because it’s in the wrong format or the date and time is not valid (like month 13 or hour 25). It will accept `2018-01-22T18:23:00Z` and `2018-01-22T18:23:00.000000000Z` too. This should be OK for most purposes since it is still allowed within the ISO 8601 standard. It will require that seconds are present, though: It will not accept `2018-01-22T18:23Z`. A quick solution if you need this is `OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-01-22T18:23Z").toInstant()`. It doesn’t validate that the offset in the string is `Z`, though.

You may want to add a range check. Probably instants that are too far into the past or the future should be considered invalid for your application. Use `Instant.isBefore()` and/or `Instant.isAfter()`.

Don’t use a regular expression. It will be complicated to write and *very, very* complicated to read for those maintaining your code. If you do need more detailed syntax validation, including the case where you need to accept minutes precision with no seconds, use a `DateTimeFormatter` as already mentioned in [Akshay Batra’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49623685/5772882).

Comment: This method didn't work for me when I've applied it to the instant with minute precision: e.g. `2018-01-22T18:23Z`. It did work fine for nanoseconds, milliseconds and seconds precision

Comment: Right you are, @TaoufikMohdit. A quick solution is `OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-01-22T18:23Z").toInstant()`. It doesn’t validate that the offset in the string is `Z`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Create a String called "format", and put the required format there. After that try below code and check if dt returns anything

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format);//required format
LocalDateTime dt = formatter.parse(oldstring);
```